# Select selected combobox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've these three selects:

```
<div id ="Xcombos" class = "styled-select">
  <select id="combopie" class="Xcombo" style="display:none;">
    <option value="gender">Gender</option>
    <option value="age">Age</option>
  </select>
  <select id="combobar" class="Xcombo" style="display:none;">
    <option value="date">Date</option>
    <option value="age">Age</option>
  </select>
  <select id="comboline" class="Xcombo" style="display:none;">
    <option value="date">Date</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The user should select only one of this 5 `options values` (gender, age, date, age, date)

I was using this:

```
var Xcombo_values = $('#Xcombos .Xcombo').val()
```

But this only gives me values of the first `select`.

How Can I grab the value of selected option ?

Cheers

**Update :**

radio:

```
<input type="radio" name="tipo" id="pie" value="pie" /><label for="pie">
<input type="radio" name="tipo" id="bar" value="bar" /><label for="bar">
<input type="radio" name="tipo" id="line" value="line" /><label for="line">

$(function () {
    $('input[type=\'radio\']').click(function () {
        $('select.Xcombo').hide();
        $('#combo' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#Xcombos .Xcombo option").val()`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, no its not working, it keeps selecting the same first option, "gender"

Comment: Well, the next one is'nt selected, so how do you expect it to work. They are also hidden, so you would need to first show the dropdown, so  that something else can be selected, then bind a function to the change event etc.

Comment: If you don't have any additional logic in place that will prevent a user from selecting more than one option, how should the code decide which one to take?

Comment: @devnull69, update code to better understood

Comment: adeneo's response below should be fine then

Comment: @devnull69, im trying to use that, I think its close but i need to "grab" that selected option value into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As easy as:

```
var selected = $('#combopie option:selected').val();
```

You can play with it in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EnWvN/

**EDIT**

And if you want to retrieve the selected option of each select:

```
var select_values = [],
    sel_val;

$('.Xcombo').each(function () {
    sel_val = $(this).children(':selected').val();
    select_values.push(sel_val);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EnWvN/4/

(In the example I bound the code to the change event. The relevant to you is what is fired, not how)

And to get the value of a radio, is pretty much of the same. Just use the following to get each single value:

```
$("#the_id_of_your_form input[name='the_name_of_your_radio']:checked").val();
```

Comment: but my select isnt only combopie.

Comment: Yes but the method to retrieve the selected option of each of them is the same. The rest is just collecting the info you want. I'll update the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Didn't it help? You should choose a right answer if you want people to continue helping you in future.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function () {
        $('select.Xcombo').hide();
        var comboSelected = $('[name="tipo"]').filter(':checked').val();
        $('#combo' + comboSelected).show();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aJF8L/)

Comment: it looks be some a problem with that, mouseover or clicking seems making some kinda of confusing

Comment: im using your code, but its not working...I need a varibale to store the selected option value, eg: comboSelected = "age"

Comment: @user1148875 - edited the answer to use a variable, as I'm not really sure what you mean?

Comment: The code to simply get the correct value: `$('#combo' + comboSelected).val()`